# Designing a Stress Testing Framework

Tags: frameworks, stress-testing

I do a sort of integration/stress test on a very large product (think operating-system size), and recently my team and I have been discussing ways to better organize our test workloads. Up until now, we've been content to have all of our (custom) workload applications in a series of batch-type jobs each of which represent a single stress-test run. Now that we're at a point where the average test run involves upwards of 100 workloads running across 13 systems, we think it's time to build something a little more advanced.

I've seen a lot out there about unit testing frameworks, but very little for higher-level stress type tests. Does anyone know of a common (or uncommon) way that the problem of managing large numbers of workloads is solved?

Right now we would like to keep a database of each individual workload and provide a front-end to mix and match them into test packages depending on what kind of stress we need on a given day, but we don't have any examples of the best way to do more advanced things like ranking the stress that each individual workload places on a system.

What are my fellow stress testers on large products doing? For us, a few handrolled scripts just won't cut it anymore.

Comment: I can't really help you, but here are two links to available tools for evaluation. http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php http://www.testingfaqs.org/t-load.html

Answer (score 1):

My own experience has been initially on IIS platform with WCAT  and latterly with JMeter and Selenium.

WCAT and JMeter both allow you to walk through a web site as a route, completing forms etc. and record the process as a script. The script can then be played back singly or simulating multiple clients and multiple threads. Randomising the play back to simulate lumpy and unpredictable use etc.

The scripts can be edited and or can be written by hand once you know whee you are going. WCAT will let you play back from the log files as well allowing you simulate real world usage.

Both of the above are installed on a PC or server.

Selenium is a FireFox add in but works in a similar way recording and playing back scripts and allowing for scaling up.

Somewhat harder is working out the scenarios you are testing for and then designing the tests to fit them. Also Interaction with the database and other external resouces need to be factored in. Expcet to spend a lot of time looking at log files, so good graphical output is essential.

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult thing for me was to collect and organized performance metrics from servers under load. Performance Monitor was my main tool. When Visual Studio Tester edition came up I was astonished how easy it was to work with performance counters. They pre-packaged a list of counters for a web server, SQL server, ASP.NET application, etc. I learned about a bunch of performance counters I did not know even exist. In addition you can collect your own counters too. You can store metrics after each run. You can also connect to production servers and see how they are feeling today. Then I see all those graphics in real time I feel empowered! :)  If you need more load you can get VS Load Agents and create load generating rig (or should I call it botnet). Comparing to over products on the market it is relatively inexpensive. MS license goes per processor but not per concurrent request. That means you can produce as much load as your hardware can handle. On average, I was able to get about 3,000 concurrent web requests on dual-core, 2GB memory computer. In addition you can incorporate performance tests into your builds.

Of course it goes for Windows. Besides the price tag of about $6K for the tool could be a bit high, plus the same amount of money per additional load agent.